# Assembly Language Brute Force

Tags: assembly, brute-force, motorola, 68000

So i am working on an assembly language program to determine the optimum dimensions of a closed cylindrical can, such as those used for canning food products. There are three input variables, which i have already created the calculus portion in assembly language code:

The cost of the end material in dollars/cm2.

The cost of the side material in dollars/cm2.

The volume of the can in milliliters.

Given these three input variables, i have determined the dimensions (height and diameter) of the can such that the cost of the can is minimized. Again i have came up with the calculus portion to solving this program but curious as to what a brute force would look like using a `do` or `while` loop. How would one go about doing to create a brute force that generates pretty much the same output as the calculus answer, for example:

```
Enter the cost of end material per square cm: 
.001
Enter the cost of the side material per square cm: 
.003
Enter the desired volume in milliliters: 
100

Calculus Answer:

Can cost:  0.24
Diameter:  7.25
Height:    2.41  

Brute Force Answer:

Can cost:  0.24
Diameter:  7.25
Height:    2.41
```

The calculus portion that i have come up with resulting in a calculus answer output is:

```
********** CONSTANTS **********
TWO:           EQU    $40000000        
PI:            EQU    $40490FDA
ONE_THIRD:     EQU    $3EAAAAAb
START_R:       EQU    $3C23D70A
*******************************

start:  initIO                  * Initialize (required for I/O)
        initF
        setEVT
        lineout  p1
        floatin  buffer
        cvtaf    buffer,D5   * END cost
        lineout  p2
        floatin  buffer
        cvtaf    buffer,D6   * SIDE cost
        lineout  p3
        floatin  buffer
        cvtaf    buffer,D7   * VOLUME

**********************************************************************
** Calculus Answer
** Formula for the radius of the optimum can:
** radius = (((volume*side_cost)/(2*PI*end_cost))^(1/3)      

** numerator, volume*side_cost:
        move.l      D7,D1       * VOLUME
        fmul        D6,D1       * VOLUME*SIDE_COST 

** denominator, 2*PI*end_cost        
        move.l      D5,D2       * END_COST
        fmul        #TWO,D2     * END_COST * 2.0
        fmul        #PI,D2      * END_COST * 2.0 * PI

** now take result to 1/3 power
        fdiv        D2,D1        * numerator/denominator
        move.l      #ONE_THIRD,D0              
        fpow        D1,D0       *(numerator/denominator) ^ (1/3)

** Calulus answer done, now calculate diameter, height, cost
        move.l      D0,D1       * D1 has radius
        fmul        #TWO,D0     * D0 has diameter        
        cvtfa       diameter,#2

** calculate height = (volume / PI*r^2)
        move.l      D1,D2       * radius
        fmul        D2,D2       * radius^2
        fmul        #PI,D2      * radius^2*PI
        move.l      D7,D3       * copy of volume
        fdiv        D2,D3       * vol / PI*radius^2  HEIGHT --> D3
        move.l      D3,D0      
        cvtfa       height,#2

** calculate cost = SIDE_COST*SIDE_SURFACE + 2*END_COST*END_SURFACE
        *** side cost:
        move.l      #PI,D2
        fmul        #TWO,D2     * 2*PI
        fmul        D1,D2       * 2*PI*radius
        fmul        D3,D2       * 2*PI*radius*height  = side surface area
        fmul        D6,D2       * side surface area * SIDE_COST

        *** end cost:
        move.l      #PI,D0
        fmul        #TWO,D0     * 2*PI
        fmul        D1,D0       * 2*PI*radius
        fmul        D1,D0       * 2*PI*radius*radius
        fmul        D5,D0       * 2*PI*radius*radius*END_COST
        fadd        D2,D0
        cvtfa       cost,#2

** DONE, print the  calculus answer

        lineout     ans1
        lineout     ans2
        lineout     ans3
```

How might it be if one wanted to create a brute force for this program using a 'do' or 'while' loop like below. Can someone help me.

```
radius = 0.01
lastCost = Calculate

do:
    radius = radius+0.01
    newCost = Calculate
    if(newCost  lastCost)
        goto print
    lastCost = newCost
    goto loop
print lastcost
```

**just curious as to what a brute force method might look like for this, im pretty sure it is basically the same code but just adding a couple of lines of code. I just want to know where might i add those lines of code.**

Comment: No it is not, i know it might sound like one though

Comment: please specify/tag instruction set.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by "specify/tag instruction set"

Comment: What is the processor you are targeting? Please add a tag that marks the instruction set of the processor you are targeting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if I understand you correctly you only have to calculate ALL combinations of height and width and take the lowest cost.the problem here is to find an interval which will include the best answer, but also a stepsize which is feasible for you current problem (otherwise you will have too many possibilities)
You also need to set the side condition with height*width²*pi = fixed volumina because if the volumina is smaller (which could happen from some combinations) then the cost would also be smaller

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a range (initially 0 to max) and select N points at equal distances within this range (including the min and the max). Of these N points find the point with the best price, and the points on the left/right of it become the new range (or the point itself if it was the old min or max). Of course you'd stop when you reach the required amount of precision, whatever that is.

For your case "N = 4" should be enough; and you can remember the values from the previous iteration (e.g. with "N = 4" you'd only calculate 2 points per iteration as you'd know the values at min and max already). For N = 4, the range would decrease by 25% each iteration, and after 17 iterations the range would be less than 1% of the original range (and you would've only calculated 36 prices).